# angular2 login catch error in component

Tags: angular

My authentication service has login function as follows:

```js
private _authenticationUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' + 'rest-auth/';  // URL to web api

  login(username: string, password: string) {

    let body = JSON.stringify({
      'username' : username, 
      'password': password
    });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.http.post(this._authenticationUrl + 'login/', body, options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError).subscribe( data => this.setToken(data.key),
      error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

Base service is as follows:

```js
@Injectable()
export class BaseService {

  constructor (protected http: Http) {

  }
  /*http://127.0.0.1:8000/*/
  /*http://www.swarms.berlin:8000/*/
   public _baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';  // URL to web api
   protected token = localStorage.getItem('token');


    public extractData(res: Response) {
      if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
        throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
      }
      let body = res.json();
      return body || { };
    }

    public handleError (error: any) {
      let errMsg = error.message || 'Server error';
      console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
      return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

and my login component is as follows:

```js
onSubmitLogin() {
  if(!this.username || !this.password) {return;}
    this._loginService.login(
        this.username, 
        this.password
        );
  }
```

How can I handle or access login error in component so that I can show on my html as error message?

Comment: Maybe define login the method of your service as observable, which the component can subscribe. And on catch, return that error to component (which will then show error..?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , you've injected the service inside your component already , so :

```
export class MyComponent {
   private loginError ;
   construcor(){
     this.loginError = this._loginService.errorMessage
   }
   onSubmitLogin() {
      if(!this.username || !this.password) {return;}
        this._loginService.login(
            this.username, 
            this.password
            );
      }
}
```

That was easiest way , there are heaps of other ways too :

1- To let the component do the subscription :

Your service  :

```
return this.http.post(this._authenticationUrl + 'login/', body, options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError)
```

Your component :

```
if(!this.username || !this.password) {return;}
    this._loginService.login(
        this.username, 
        this.password
        )
        .subscribe( data => this._loginService(data.key),
          error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```